# boringSSL dart 1.12 on Windows

Tags: ssl, dart, boringssl

I am having issues making an http.get() request since I updated to dart 1.12. I am using Windows 10 to develop on with IntelliJ IDEA (15 EAP) as the editor.  When I send a request I get the following error:

864050208:error:100be07e:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED:src\ssl\s3_clnt.c:1031:

[2015-9-10 9:52:56.021] HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: Unknown error from BoringSSL library, errno = 0)

I have looked up the issue and only one source was found but did not fix the Problem. https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/24208

Can someone explain what I need to do to fix this issue?

Code:

I am getting the error when requesting the token

```
var requestAuthToken= await http.post('https://identity.api.rackspacecloud.com/v2.0/tokens', headers : {'Content-Type':'application/json'}, body: JSON.encode({"auth": {"RAX-KSKEY:apiKeyCredentials":{"username":"XXXXXXXX","apiKey":"XXXXXXXXXXXXX"}}}));

var authResponse = JSON.decode(requestAuthToken.body);
String token = authResponse['access']['token']['id'];

List<int> binaryData = [11,22,44,111,333...];

var upload = new http.Request('PUT', Uri.parse('https://storage101.iad3.clouddrive.com/v1/MossoCloudFS_xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/testimage2.jpg'));
upload.headers['X-Auth-Token'] = token;
upload.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/jpeg';
upload.bodyBytes = binaryData;
await upload.send();
```

Comment: Do you use certificates in your code? Can you please add some code that demonstrates your problem. Do you make an http or https  request?

Comment: I added the code example. It is when I am requesting a token from https. I was not getting this issue in 1.11

Comment: Please create a bug report.

Comment: I'm not very good at filling out bug reports :P https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/24330

Comment: Nothing wrong with the report. They will add a comment if they need additional information. Thanks for posting the link.